# generate multiple random numbers in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, random

I'd like to generate size N set of random numbers in Sqlite.

Right now the best I've got is to union a set of calls to `random()` like this

```
create view random_view as
select random()
union select random()
union select random()
union select random()
union select random()
;
```

Maybe someone has a more clever solution that could generate N numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't try, but maybe this? Given any table of at least N rows,

```
SELECT RANDOM() FROM anytable LIMIT ?
```

replacing `?` with N.

Comment: Nice! Works so long as `anytable` has N rows.

Answer (score 3):

```
create temp table rtab (x integer primary key, v default (random()));

create temp trigger rtrig 
before insert on rtab
when new.x > 0 begin
   insert or replace into rtab (x) values (new.x - 1); 
end;

PRAGMA recursive_triggers = on;

insert into rtab (x) values (9);

sqlite> select * from rtab;
0|-6742468521271879323
1|-8020364160821973904
2|4567559116463208288
3|5330277995838989553
4|-9000358059551141276
5|-7148307065140334921
6|8156512560793181351
7|-10751076681323044
8|-7335834651732027766
9|6837665741304560539
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need millions of rows and have shell/bash, it might be good enough this way:

`echo -e '.import "/dev/stdin" mytable\n'; sleep 0.5 ; for i in {1..10000000}; do echo $RANDOM; done) | sqlite3 my.db`

The sleep step is critical to prevent sqlite from reading the first numbers as SQL commands due to buffering. YMMV

Comment: Yeah, if you can run external commands then getting a random number from /dev/random, perl, python or anywhere is pretty easy. I was trying to do it purely in the SQLite. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [recursive query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte).

This query generates a table with 1000 random numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE test(field1);

INSERT INTO test
  WITH RECURSIVE
    cte(x) AS (
       SELECT random()
       UNION ALL
       SELECT random()
         FROM cte
        LIMIT 1000
  )
SELECT x FROM cte;
```

Comment: If you replace the second call to `random()` to `*` the number ends up being the same.  However, replacing the first select with `select 1` causes the first row to be `1`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [generate_series()](https://www.sqlite.org/series.html) table function. The docs show this example which generates 20 random integer values:

```
SELECT random() FROM generate_series(1,20);
```

Comment: `generate_series()` is not included in the standard SQLite distribution. It's a loadable extension.

Comment: Since 2020-12-01 (3.34.0) this function is built into the SQLite CLI. You're correct, however, that if one is using SQLite from a library then you'd have to load it.